# Why for random matrix one of eigenvalues is so big?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, random-matrices

Here i have the image of eigenvalues for matrixes obtained with $rand(n,n)/sqrt(n)$, why one of the eigenvalues for every matrix is so big on real axis comparatively to the others?

[image]

EDIT: i have several experiments for every matrix size, every time i have only one outstandingly big eigenvalue.

```
green: 8*8
blue: 16*16
red: 32*32
cyan: 64*64
```

EDIT: **In case i use $randn$ instead of $rand$ while forming matrices, i have no *outlier*.**

Observation: When matrix generated with rand, all elements are close to 1/2. So, you can fit vector to have biggest eigenvalue near $n/2.$ This is the same as in the case of Markov chains, matrix has eigenvalue 1 and some smaller eigenvalues.

Comment: Please explain the symbolism of the plot. Is each color the eigenvalues of one random matrix? If so there seem to be _several_ largish eigenvalues for each of them -- interestingly enough they seem to be clustered in each experiment.

Comment: If you try the example (Matlab: `A=rand(64);D=eig(A);scatter(real(D),imag(D))`), you see that there is only one. OP must be plotting eigenvalues for several matrices of each size.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to verify the semicircular law, the elements need to be chosen from a Gaussian distribution, which is why `randn` has no outliers.

The outlier effect is a consequence of Perron-Frobenius theory; you are generating a non-negative matrix, so there is a single largest real eigenvalue, and all the others are strictly smaller. There is apparently a theorem about a similar scenario (symmetric real) described here: http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2012/05/16/the-curious-case-of-random-eigenvalues/